# Linux tool to bulk change a website from http:// to https://

Tags: linux, http, https, methodology

I need to change an entire PHP-based website from `http://` to `https://`. The SSL certificate has already been installed and shows validity.

Now, the website has many many subdirectories, shops, newsletters etc., but stems from one major directory.

Is there either a tool or a methodology I can do this under Linux recursively, i. e. incorporating all various sub-directories in my search and automatically exchange `http://` to `https://`? Is there a way not only to do the exchange but also to save the changed files automatically?

Maybe a stupid question, but I'd appreciate your help a lot so as to prevent myself from going through every single PHP file in every single directory.

Comment: How about just creating a `htaccess` rule that forwards all http requests to https?

Comment: Yes, thank you, Daniel, this has already been done, but as long as there are hardcoded http:// calls in the PHP files, it will always show you the (i) sign on the left of your URL. This is the issue for me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` command has an in-place option which can be helpful in executing your change. For example

```
sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

In your case this may work

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\//https:\/\//g' ./*.php
```

I would recommend a backup before you try this since the `sed` command `-i` option may work differently on your system.

Here is a [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112023/how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-files/112024#112024) with more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, Stephen, I think this is the one I will check out right now. I will tell you about its success.

Comment: Hello, Stephen,

with a slight modification to ...

sed -e 's/http:\/\//https:\/\//g' -i.bak $(find . -type f -name '*.php')

... the job could be finished excellently.

Many thanks again

Markus

Comment: a less cluttered command is find . -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's|http://|https://|g' {} \;
This will find all files with php extension in the present directory where this command is run and within subdirectories and replace http:// with https://